# Querying many-To-many relationship with a list of parameters

Tags: entity-framework, linq, many-to-many, entity-framework-core

I use EF core and i have the classes "User" and "Authority" which are connected with a many-to-many relationship ("Users" has a property "authorities" and "Authority" has a property "users"). The relationship is managed via middle class "UserAuthority".

I need to query all "Users" that have "Authorities" with certain names.

I tried this:

```
List<string> authorities = A list of authorities;
(from user in this.dbContext.user.Include("authorities.authority")
 where authorities.Any(x => user.authorities.Any(y => y.authority.authority == x))
 select new UserDto(user.id, user.firstname + " " + user.lastname)).ToList()
```

But the console says that LINQ cant translate

```
authorities.Any(x => user.authorities.Any(y => y.authority.authority == x))
```

and that it will be handled in memory.

What is the correct approach here?

Answer (score 1):

Currently the only translatable in-memory collection method is `Contains` (for primitive type in-memory collection, translates to SQL `IN(...)`).

So instead of

```
authorities.Any(x => user.authorities.Any(y => y.authority.authority == x))
```

use

```
user.authorities.Any(ua => authorities.Contains(ua.authority.authority))
```

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure this works. May be you have other non translatable parts, like `UserDto` constructor - you didn't provide the model, so I can't test myself. What does the warning say after applying the above modification?

Comment: When i remove the manyToMany where clause, or if i remove the "contains" part and replace it with `authorities.ElementAt(0) == ua.authority.authority`, then there are no warnings (but then it generates 2 sqls for some reason and i cant find the `authorities.ElementAt(0) == ua.authority.authority` part in them)

Comment: and i would need to send you a screenshot to show u the console, the warning massag is quite big

Comment: I'm testing on the latest 2.2, and with a similar model structure the original issue is reproduced, but `Contains` works. So something strange is happening in your environment. What EF Core version are you using? Can you provide a full repro (e.g. [mcve[)?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> i have the classes "User" and "Authority" which are connected with a many-to-many relationship ("Users" has a property "authorities" and "Authority" has a property "users").

Something like this:

```
class User
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ...

    // every User has zero or more Authorities (many-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Authority> Authorities {get; set;}
}
class Authority
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    ...

    // every Authority has zero or more Users (many-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users {get; set;}
}
```

> I need to query all "Users" that have "Authorities" with certain names.

If I read this literally, you want all `Users`, that have at least one `Authority` that has a `Name` that is in the collection of `certainNames`. You want each `User` with ALL his `Authorities`, even those `Authorities` with names that are not in `certainNames`

It could also mean that you want all `Users`, each with only those of their `Authorities` that have a `Name` which is in `certainNames`, but only those `Users` that have at least one such `Authority`.

How about this:

```
IEnumerable<string> certainNames = ...
var UsersWithAuthoritiesThatAreInCertainNames = myDbContext.Users
    .Where (user => user.Authorities.Select(authority => authority.Name)
         .Intersect(certainNames)
         .Any())
    .Select(user => new
    {
         // select only the User properties you actually plan to use:
         Id = user.Id,
         Name = user.Name,
         ...

         Authorities = user.Authorities.Select(authority => new
         {
             // again select only the Authority properties you plan to use:
             Id = authority.Id,
             Name = authority.Name,
             ...
         })
         .ToList(),
    })
```

In words:

From the collection of all users, keep only those users, that have at least one authority with a name that is also in certainNames. From the remaining users, select several properties.

If you don't want ALL Authorities of the user, but only the ones that are in certain names:

```
var UsersWithOnlyTheirAuthoritiesThatAreInCertainNames = myDbContext.Users
    .Select(user => new
    {
         // select only the User properties you actually plan to use:
         Id = user.Id,
         Name = user.Name,
         ...

         Authorities = user.Authorities
         .Where(authority => certainNames.Contains(authority.Name))
         .Select(authority => new
         {
             // again select only the Authority properties you plan to use:
             Id = authority.Id,
             Name = authority.Name,
             ...
         })
         .ToList(),
    })
    // keep only the Users that have at least one such authority
    .Where(selectedUser => selectedUser.Authorities.Any());
```

In words:

from the collection of Users, select some properties of every user, inclusive some properties of only those Authorities of the user that have a name that is also in certainNames. From the remaining sequence of selected users keep only those users that have at least one authority left

Comment: Did you miss the EF **Core** tag? Or forget that EF Core currently **requires** explicit join entity for many-to-many?